# JavaScript & XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I know that due to JavaScript security sandbox, it is not possible to load xml data from outside of  the domain which the JavaScript code is on.

But if I am using the localhost:8080 and the xml document is coming from the localhost in the same machine but from another port like 8081, is this considered as same domain or not?

Thanks

andy e and ken and jacob, thank you all :-)

Comment: jsonp is a solution to this problem. you insert a script tag with a callback in the query string. When the script is executed it calls the callback passing the returned xml as a argument.

Answer (score 5):

Different port is considered "different origin", and thus violates the same origin policy.

```
URL                                                Outcome   Reason
=================================================================================
http://store.company.com/dir2/other.html           Success   
http://store.company.com/dir/inner/another.html    Success   
https://store.company.com/secure.html              Failure   Different protocol
http://store.company.com:81/dir/etc.html           Failure   Different port
http://news.company.com/dir/other.html             Failure   Different host
```

Source(s): [Same origin policy for JavaScript - MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), [Same origin policy - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).